# Map two different routes to the same controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am working on extending the example at: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-web-api.html

They have a ToDo apis: `/api/todo` and `/api/todo/{id}`.

I want to extend it to ToDoGroups `/api/ToDoGroup`.

Under ToDoGroup, I want to reach a ToDo by the follwoing:
`/api/ToDoGroup/{id}/ToDo/{id}`.

How can I make it point to the same controller action? For example the following action below will also have another route like `[HttpGet("ToDoGroup/{ToDoGroupid}/ToDo/{ToDoid}", Name = "GetTodo")]`

```
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetTodo")]
public IActionResult GetById(string id)
{
    var item = TodoItems.Find(id);
    if (item == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return new ObjectResult(item);
}
```

Comment: you tagged this with both asp.net core and asp.net web api. While they are very similar, they can have slightly different routing syntax.

Comment: HI @Mike_G, The link said the following in its title "Web API with ASP.NET Core". I am still learinign the differences and no expert. Can I change the comment tag now?

Comment: Right, just wanted you to know there is a diff between "Asp.net Web Api", and a "Web Api built with Asp.Net Core".  Its no biggie, just be aware there is a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first change the controller's route prefix:

```
      [Route("api/todogroup/{groupId:int}")]
      public class TodoController : Controller
```

then change your action's route:

```
      [HttpGet("todo/{id}", Name = "GetTodo")]
      public IActionResult GetById(int groupId, string id)
```

**edit:**
to get both routes, you can do this:

```
        [Route("api")]
      public class TodoController : Controller 

          [HttpGet("todo/{id}", Name = "GetTodo")]//api/todo/43
      public IActionResult GetById(string id)

      [HttpGet("todogroup/{groupdId:int}/todo/{id}", Name = "GetGroupTodo")]//api/todogroup/100/todo/43
      public IActionResult GetById(int groupId, string id)
```

Asp.Net Web Api has a way of negating a route prefix (the route specified on the controller), but I cant find an equivalent in Asp.Net Core.

Comment: I would like the route ToDoGroup/{ToDoGroupid}/ToDo/{ToDoid} in addition to ToDo/{ToDoid}. They should return the same ToDo since the ToDo id is unique. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Thanks!  Let me know if there are useful links I can read up on.